# Getting errors after installing Productivity Power Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

I've just downloaded and installed the **Productivity Power Tools** for Visual Studio 2010. I got out of VS 2010, and got back in, so that it would load the new add-in. The moment it got back in I started to get a lot of error messages. For example:

- "The 'VSTS for Database Professionals
  Sql Server Data-tier Application'
  package did not load correctly."
- "The 'RadLangSvc.Pac​kage,
  RadLangSvc.VS, Version=10.0.0.​0,
  Culture=neutral​, PublicKeyToken=​' package did not load
  correctly."
- "The 'Language Package' package did
  not load correctly."

This is just some of the error messages I got immediately after installing this add-in. In all cases, after each error message there was the additional text:

"The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension."  (Somewhat of an obvious comment here.)

Have others experienced this problem with the Productivity Power Tools add-in?  Is the only way of solving this problem, is to uninstall it?  Or is there another way of making it work?  (There are things in this add-in, which I would really like to use.)

Comment: At that time, no. It eventually worked itself out.

Comment: I also had exactly this problem. I updated my nuget package manager form 1.x to 2.8. This solved all my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried uninstalling the addon, installing [Visual Studio 2010 - Service Pack 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718359.aspx) and then reinstalling the addon after?

Comment: I thought I had already applied SP1 for VS 2010, but I'm not sure.  How can I tell?

Comment: Open Visual Studio and go to Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio. At the top of the newly window box it should say something like "Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1 Rel" (That's what mine is anyway). SP1 will indicate if it's installed or not

Comment: OK, I've just checked and I don't have that version.  I've got 10.0.30319.1  RTMRel.  I'll get SP1.

Comment: It took a while, but I've finally installed SP1 for VS 2010.  Now I'm at the same version as you, Jamie.  However, I forgot to uninstall the addon before applying SP1.  Should I uninstall the addon, and then install it again?

Comment: Hi Jamie. I know it's been a while since I contacted you about this.  I've been living with these error messages, as they didn't seem to interfer with anything I did. However, now I'm trying to learning how to use Entity Framework, doing model-first development, and now it's a show stopper. Do I have to uninstall VS 2010 SP1 and the Productivity Power Tools, then install VS 2010 SP1, then the Power tools?

Comment: Hello Rod, I think it would be best if you uninstall the add-on, then VS2010 SP1 and then reapply both SP1 and the add-on. If for some reason this does not work then I think you may have to consider reinstalling VS2010 completely (Although other users on here might have a better idea).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on both my home and work computers. These exact steps worked on one of them.

- Uninstall *all* addons that cause errors to occur.
- Locate your Visual Studio 2010 installation media.
- In the \WCU\DAC folder, you’ll find three MSIs;

  ```
  DACFramework_enu.msi
  DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi
  TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi
  ```

  - Run and install each of them.
- Reapply Visual Studio 2010 SP1.
- Reinstall the addons.

As with most microsoft products I presume it was the sequence in which I did things that made it work one time and not the other. I suggest if this doesnt solve the issue you mix and skip steps as appropriate until you get it working.

One additional step I used was to run Visual Studio from the command line as follows;

```
devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
```

I did this before uninstalling and reinstalling the addons. Whether it made a difference is debatable, but in the interest of full disclosure...

Comment: var IThink = (ProductivityPowerTools is Awesome); :P

Answer (score 1):

The thing that did it for me was installing the .NET 4.5 framework.
It is not necessary to re-install VS2010 SP1.